# SQL trigger that creates another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to make a trigger, that creates a new table when a row is inserted in the trigger table, where the name of the new table is what was inserted in a specific column in the table with the trigger?

Something like this?
`CREATE TRIGGER playlists.insert_trigger ON playlists AFTER INSERT AS  name = SELECT name FROM playlists WHERE id = max(id) CREATE TABLE name (id int, song varchar(255));`

Answer (score 0):

Table creation is an operation which causes implicit commit.

[Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html)

So this operation is not possible in the trigger.